# What happens when an opened key is deleted or renamed?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

Is the behavior documented/defined anywhere for the following situations:

1. Process A opens key "foo", process B opens key "foo" and then deletes it.
2. Process A opens key"foo", process B opens key "foo" and then renames it to "bar".

I've found in both cases that process B's operation will succeed - and closing the handle in A still works too. But what is really happening here?

There seems to be a lot of edge causes that make this hard to understand. For example what would happen in case 1 if after process B deletes the key, process A attempts to rename the deleted key or create new sub keys under it?

Comment: The rename operation is undocumented, so to all effects and purposes you should consider its behaviour to be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RegDeleteKeyEx::](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A deleted key is not removed until the last handle to it is closed.

Comment: What about the rename case?

Comment: There is no rename operation using any one particular WINAPI. You have to make a copy of Reg Tree you want to rename, then delete it, then create new (renamed) key same as the Reg tree you have copied earlier.

Comment: This is using ZwRenameKey

Comment: That is a low-level call. But still, I think, they would follow the same flow of copying, deleting and then creating new keys. Don't have further ideas on this. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by copy, delete and create?

Comment: Renaming Flow Example: (From foo_orgnl to foo_renamed)
`1. Copy the whole foo_orgnl.`
`2. Delete the existing foo_orgnl.`
`3. Create a new foo_renamed.`
`4. Paste (Create all) the copied foo_orgnl.`